# Commute partial trace operator and measurement operator

Tags: measurement, quantum-operation

Suppose I have a general measurement $M$ applying on n-qubit registers. So we are able to use the **POVM** notation, where $\sum_m M_m = I$ and $M_m = E_m^\dagger E_m$.

And I want to know the exact behavior of $M$ exactly on i-th register. So, can we find a specific measurement on the i-th register, called $\tilde{M_i}$, s.t. $\mathcal{E_i}\circ M(\cdot) = \tilde{M_i}\circ\mathcal{E_i}(\cdot)(EQ1)$, where superoperator $\mathcal{E_i}$ represents as partial trace out all but i-th register, or equivalently, $\mathcal{E_i} = \sum_{\{j_1,j_2,...j_n\}\backslash\{{j_i}\}}(\langle j_1|\otimes...\otimes I_i\otimes...)(\cdot)(|j_1\rangle\otimes...\otimes I_i\otimes...)$.

My question is, can we find such $\tilde{M_i}$ which satisfies $(EQ1)$? Notice that, measurement $\tilde{M_i}$ only acts on the i-th register.

So for example, when we consider quantum differential privacy and defines the neighboring condition of two product states $\rho = \rho_1 \otimes ...\otimes \rho_n$ and
$\sigma = \sigma_1 \otimes ... \otimes \sigma_n$ as they differs only on i-th register, which means $\forall j\in[n]\backslash\{i\}, \rho_j = \sigma_j$, and $\rho_i \ne \sigma_i$. Now we have a measurement $M$ on these n registers. What I want to do is to maximize the ratio between the following two probabilities:

$\frac{\Pr[M(\rho) = m]}{\Pr[M(\sigma) = m]}$, where m is some classical output corresponding to measurement $M$. So can we find a specific measurement on exactly i-th register $\tilde{M_i}$ satisfies that it can exactly capture the probabilistic characteristics s.t. the ratio is at most:

$\frac{\sum_j\Pr[\tilde{M_i}(\rho_i) = m_j^i]}{\sum_j\Pr[\tilde{M_i}(\sigma_i) = m_j^i]}$.

Comment: Your notation makes it look like you mean "general measurement" as some kind of function. Can you clarify which definition you're using precisely (by editing the post, *not* in the comments)? Also, if $\tilde M_i$ is also a "measurement" on the $i$-th register, I don't understand the question: you said $\mathcal E_i$ is partial trace on $i$-th register, so after it there's no $i$-th register to measure, and I'm not sure how to make sense of $\tilde M_i\circ\mathcal E_i$

Comment: As @glS explained, it's not clear what the post means, but it appears quite likely that any clarification will contradict the statement "quantum error correcting codes exist" and therefore the answer is probably going to be "No, we can't find such a measurement on the $i$-th register".